# How does The Pirate Bay mask itself from its VPS providers?

Tags: vps, virtual-machines, encryption, privacy

From https://torrentfreak.com/pirate-bay-moves-to-the-cloud-becomes-raid-proof-121017/

> The hosting providers have no idea that they’re hosting The Pirate Bay, and even in the event they found out it would be impossible for them to gather data on the users.

How do they achieve that? Specifically, I'm interested in the VM part, because normally your VM image can be inspected by the provider at any time no problem. So how do you obfuscate your activities from someone who has root *and* physical access to your thing?

Comment: Did you read the article you linked? It explains how they achieved that.

Comment: Not in enough detail that I could repeat what they've done.

Comment: Then at at least tell us what your knowledge base and expertise is. Otherwise, there's know way to know how much detail it would take. (Do you know what a load balancer is and what the traffic coming out of it looks like versus what goes into it?)

Answer (score 1):

The VM only sees what comes out of their load balancer. They don't let anything they don't want their provider to see come out of their load balancer. The article you linked explains this.

For example, they don't want their VPS provider to see the source IP address of queries they receive. So they make sure this information *never* goes into the traffic from the load balancer to the VPS.

Comment: So, the VM images themselves are in no way special?

Comment: They might be special in any number of ways, I don't know. But the key is that information they don't want the VPS provider to have never goes anywhere near the VPS.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 things in the article:

1. TPB's Load balancer (could be using something like Nginx - reverse proxy)
2. Transit router (aka LSR in MPLS network - probably taking cue from CDN concept) - diskless!
3. Cloud VM

Traffic flow:
User >> (TPB Load Balancer) >> 'Encrypted' >> Transit router >> 'Encrypted' >> Cloud VM

And VM disk image is encrypted - so there is no way for the cloud hosting provider to access it. Even if the cloud provider tap the network traffic at the vm side, its 'encrypted'.

And also a failsafe - 8hrs no connection to LB, vm shuts down.

Just my 2 cents.

Comment: Can the VM provider *easily* inspect the RAM of a VM without interfering with its operation?